# using skstoreproductviewcontroller to allow users to download apps for free

Tags: ios, skproduct

Trying to find a way to allow users to download apps for free with the developers permission. (Like a free app a day) but not having the app store pricing change. **Is there a way to use the skstoreproductviewcontroller in order to allow users to download an app as a promotion for free without making that app free on the app store itself?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. In order to make the app free, you would have to make it free everywhere (in the App Store and in the `SKStoreProductViewController` as well).